# How to convert List<String[]> to List<int[]>?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to cast a list of string arrays to a list of int arrays. I have tried the following:

```
List<int[]> dataset = Read(fileName, separator).Select(
    line => Array.ConvertAll(line, s => int.Parse(s)
);
```

Read return a list of string array: `List<String[]> dataset`

Comment: You cannot **cast** string to an int, you can **convert (parse)** it.

Comment: a simple loop might be easier to understand and debug

Comment: Thats what i meant, sorry.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: but he uses int.Parse

Comment: Just add `ToList()` at the end. Currently it's returning `IEnumerable<int[]>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, that's right, I'm talking about wording and terms confusion :)

Comment: Are you really sure you want to parse your CSV file in this way? Have a look at http://filehelpers.net

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.ToList<T>()` to convert `.Select()` result (which is `IEnumerable<int[]>`) to a list.
This way, you apply `int.Parse` to every item of item array, and convert the result to List.
Also, in order to provide code homogeneity, you can use LINQ `Select` and `ToArray` instead of `Array.ConvertAll`:

```
List<string[]> stringArrayList = ...;
List<int[]> intArrayList = stringArrayList
    .Select(stringArray => stringArray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

One little correction: you do not **cast** string to an int, you **convert / parse** it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was trying to do!

Comment: @TimSchmelter Not sure if I understand what you mean :) Why isn't it valid? Who uses it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
List<int[]> Listintegers = yourList
    .Select(y => y.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string[]> source = new List<string[]>
{
    new string[2] { "2", "3" },
    new string[4] { "4", "5", "6", "7" },
    new string[1] { "1" }
};

List<int[]> result = source.Select(array => Array.ConvertAll(array, item => int.Parse(item))).ToList();
```